# Is there a word for when a text is between chapters that enriches the story but is not part of the previous or following chapter?

Tags: novel, formatting, structure, chapters

#### Is there a word for when a text is between chapters that enriches the story but are not part of the previous or following chapter?

I'm writing fiction and wanted to have in-universe news articles from time to time that are between the character story chapters.  I looked to see how others have done so previously, but could not find a proper word for it.

Is there a word for it?

Something like:

> Chapter 1
>
> Chapter 2
>
> **1-2 pages long text not part of chapter 2 or 3**
>
> Chapter 3

Is there a word for it, or does that sort of thing just become part of the previous or following chapter? (English is not my first language, so I'm sorry if this reads as an unclear question.)

Comment: If there is such a word, it's probably something with "inter-", but none of interlude, intermission or intermezzo seems quite right to me. NB, they might be better at https://english.stackexchange.com/ at finding a good word.

Comment: I tend to agree with @towr.  Further, the question hints that the questioner is stymied in their writing by being unable to name this type of text.  I'd just write it and move on.

Answer (score 5):

One of my favorite authors, John Brunner, did this in a number of his novels during the late 1960s and early 1970s -- *The Shockwave Rider*, *The Sheep Look Up*, and a couple others as I recall.  Robert A. Heinlein also did it in *Time Enough for Love*.

Apparently these are called an "interchapter".  This isn't quite the same as inserting a (real or fictional) quote at the beginning of a chapter (proper epigrams); those are generally selected or created to fit with the text, often symbolically, while these "interchapters" may contribute tone or background, but often don't directly advance the story.

Comment: Remember to make the interchapters, interludes, and epigrams short and to the point. What i've seen in current works are "exerpts" from in-world books or essays, small fragments that add depth and clarify worldbuilding points, often related to the theme or setting of the following chapter but rather awkward to insert into the narrative. But keep it short and easy to digest (or skip, if the reader is so inclined).

Comment: "The Winds of War" is also an example where the story has some inserts from a book written in the 60ies or 70ies by General von Roon (and translated into English by Victor Henry...)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of a word that would specify textual content that lies *between* successively numbered chapters. I don't believe people think of it this way when they layout books of fiction.

There are two ways to consider this.

### 1. Your content is the last *section* of Chapter 2 or the first *section* of Chapter 3.

In this case you would call it a section. Different formatting might make it appear like it is set off from the chapters.

My e-book version of Frank Herbert's *Dune* uses this technique. Excerpts from a book, "Manual of Muad'dib," provide lead-in text for every chapter. The text is indented like a quote, then the chapter text follows. So, in this case the text of interest is the first section of the chapter.

### 2. Your content is a *chapter* without a heading (or with a heading if you prefer)

My e-book version of Jeff Wheeler's *The Druid* uses this technique. Between successively numbered chapters he has text that is a journal entry from another point of view. It is treated like a chapter and begins on a new page like chapters. It has no heading. In the table of contents, this in-between chapter appears with the first few words of the text rather than a chapter title. But it has no number.

[image: In-between chapter from Jeff Wheeler's The Druid]

In my e-book version of Dan Brown's *Origin*, he includes short news segments (as you are wanting to do) as their own numbered chapter.

[image: Dan Brown's Origin. News segment chapter.]

While you are free to do whatever you want, when it comes to laying out the actual book, you will probably be required to choose one of these approaches: treating your in-between content as a chapter *section* or as a *chapter* on its own.